# Is it possible to use an onclick on a div?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm trying to activate `onclick` on a div.
For some reason it's not working.

Example:

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <style> 
            .box{
                border: 1px solid black;
                width: 100px; 
                height: 100px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body> 
        <div class="box" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Click', 'Facebook_Share', 'Upper_Button']);"> 

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Because for some reason it's not working.
Am I writing it wrong?
I wrote this code as an example. The JS is in the real codes `<head>`.
(It's a Google Analytics event... )

Comment: Please define "not working". Do you get an error in the console?

Comment: Here is the answer to your question - http://jsfiddle.net/KmrfN/ . As far as I know `onclick` is one of the events that can be applied to each DOM element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind the onclick element to the box div after you have loaded the Google Analytics script:

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <style> 
            .box{
                border: 1px solid black;
                width: 100px; 
                height: 100px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body> 
        <div class="box" id="tracked"> 

        </div>
        <!-- suggest using jQuery library, as it eases things, see below -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- put Google Analytics code here (I assume, the _gaq variable is the Google Analytics one) -->
        <script type="text/javascript"><!-- replace this comment with your Google Analytics code --></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function(){

              // bind click event to the box div (I used an id here)
              $("#tracked").click(function(){
                  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Click', 'Facebook_Share', 'Upper_Button']);
              });
           });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In this case the `onclick` attribute is not needed.

Comment: @GergoErdosi: Thank You, I have removed it.

Answer (score 0):

it works as expected, except that _gaq is not defined.
Define _gaq (add script, where _gaq is defined) or do something more meaningful.

```
<div class="box" onclick="alert('wakalaka');">
```